# Can I install a back bike rack without attachment to the rear part of the frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, rack

Can I install a back bike rack without attachment to the rear part of the frame?

Also, if someone can clarify, whenever I google

> bike rack

I get hits on racks designed to carry bikes on a car and such.

I am referring to the racks on the bikes themselves which will allow me to haul things on my bike.

I bought a bike recently assuming it would have attachments near the rear part of the frame but they are not present.

I have seen some bike racks which secure only to the rear wheel axle, but that does not seem too stable.

As you can see in the pic there are no holes for screwing into like I see in many other bikes and nearly all of the racks I looked at.

[image]

Comment: You asked for clarification in your question - I think the component you're looking for is called a "pannier rack". The bags that you'd put on it are called panniers.

Comment: "Bike cargo rack" should work well too.

Comment: I've also had problems getting results for that kind of rack. I have used "bike rear rack" in Google to get the one you are talking about.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Several manufacturers make replacement seatpost collars with integrated rack mount holes. Just make sure you get the right diameter for your seat tube. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I've bodged something similar in the past using scraps of metal plate, and while workable its ugly.  This is a great solution to OP's problem, given he's already bought the bike.

Comment: I've bodged something similar using P-clips, but they don't last.

Comment: This plus an adapter for mounting a rear carrier on a dropout without eyelets (e.g. from Tubus) should work nicely.

Comment: Good point, @Michael. Since he didn't include the dropouts in the photo I didn't even think whether they would have eyelets or not.

Answer (score 6):

Is the seatpost carbon? If it is replace it with an aluminium one because you'll get a number of racks that clamp to the seatpost. A rack that clamps to the seatpost would normally take up to 10kg. You may find one that also has stays that attach to the axle. Some are attached with bands to the seat-stays. This should only be done with a metal frame not a carbon one.

Answer (score 5):

A search of "bicycle cargo racks" led me to what you are looking for. You can modify your search to specify "seat post mounted racks". There are also models that clamp to the seatstays ( the frame member that goes from the axle area to the seatpost). Just check to make sure the clamps are compatible with your frame type. Clamp on racks are generally a no-go for carbon frames.

Answer (score 4):

There are various models that clamp onto the seat post (assuming it's round metal).  Topeak calls theirs ["beam rack"](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/topeak-qr-beam-rack-mtx/?lang=en&curr=GBP&dest=1&sku=5360429410&kpid=5360429410&utm_source=google&utm_term=&utm_campaign=Shopping+-+All+Products&utm_medium=base&utm_content=mckv|sjeQ83ZDN_dc|mcrid|295268872713|mkw||mmt||mrd|5360429410uk|mslid||&mkwid=sjeQ83ZDN_dc&pcrid=295268872713&prd=5360429410uk&pgrid=60973103002&ptaid=pla-586353705797&gclid=EAIaIQobChMInePV7IGw4gIVGLLtCh01Zwp1EAQYASABEgIIL_D_BwE) for example.

These tend to have a lower weight limit than conventional designs, but are still more than adequate for many uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can try searching for "pannier rack" which might give you some more results.

As to your problem, perhaps take a step back and see if a rack is what you really need. What are you planning to carry on your rack? You can get some pretty massive (expandable) saddle bags these days, or perhaps a 'floating' type of rack that attaches to your seatpost and clips or straps things onto it (as others have said, these have weight limits based on the strength of your seatpost). You could also consider a front rack if your forks have mounting holes (unlikely if the back doesn't but you never know), though this affects handling more.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider a 'bike packing seat pack' (the best search term I could find). These attach to the seat and seat post only:

[image]

There are dozens of brands and sizes and variations, and other 'bike packing' style bag mounting positions also. The idea, as far as I can tell, is a more streamlined/aero and minimalistic approach to touring, combined with being able to be mounted on frames without the pannier mounts like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which doesn't seem to have been mentioned is Thule’s Tour rack as shown [here](https://www.thule.com/en-gb/gb/bike-accessories/rear-bike-racks/thule-tour-rack-_-100090) and described in [this article](https://road.cc/content/buyers-guide/206090-your-guide-racks-and-panniers-all-your-bike-luggage-possibilities-low) - you may have seen it already but if not just scroll down to "What if my bike doesn’t have eyelets?". It's not the cheapest but looks solid and sometimes it's just good to see what your options are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by attaching it to your seat post. I have an extra collar installed around my seat post. There are also often collars that would replace the existing one so that you don't have two (and so you're clamping on the frame instead of the seat).

[image: Seatpost collar]

Answer (score -1):

Another (kludgy) option which I have not seen mentioned is to replace the quick-release bolt in your current seatpost clamp with a long regular bolt and nut, attaching the rack to those. The bolt goes first through the rack's seatpost attachment eyelet, then through the seatpost clamp, then the rack's seatpost attachment eyelet on the other side, then into the nut.

The attachment to the seatpost typically does not bear heavy loads, so may be doable with a P-clip.

Answer (score -2):

There are bicycle racks which mount directly on the rear hub which ar completely stable and effective.

Comment: Well you're right, but OP's question is about the other mount point up by the seat cluster.  The lower strutt mount is not the focus of the question.

Comment: Presumable you mean the rear dropouts, or possibly the axle, as anything mounted to the hub will not be good for carrying anything.